# ERROR: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: chartModule is not a function

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-highcharts

I was upgrading from angular 11 to 12,
I have resolved all migration errors,
Terminal is free of errors but Application is showing blank showing following message on console.

[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfjqt.png)

Here's my angular version details:[Angular-version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1MWu.png)

Here's highcharts & angular-highcharts versions:
"highcharts": "~6.0.3",
"angular-highcharts": "~5.2.0",

I tried switching back versions various times but doesn't work.

I tried to reproduce error minimally on code sandbox but couldn't be able to replicate with same dependencies.

Comment: update angular-highcharts to corresponding 12ish version

Comment: I would say, that the highcharts version needs to be updated. Please check the following guide: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#general-prerequisites

Comment: @Andrei I have tried upgrading to these versions. "angular-highcharts": "~12.0.0"; "highcharts": "~9.0.1";  Upgrading often leading to terminal full of errors related to this, "Property 'options' is private and only accessible within class 'Chart'. " There's lot of instances where chart options are modified => this.chart.options.xx. And this project uses angular-highcharts.